# Occasional error "WorkManager is not initialized properly."

Tags: android

```
OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WidgetUpdateWorker.class).build();
WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniqueWork(WidgetUpdateWorker.WIDGET_UPDATE_WORK, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, oneTimeWorkRequest);
```

The above code works fine usually. Once in a great while it throws the following exception:

```
Exception: WorkManager is not initialized properly.  You have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, have not manually called WorkManager#initialize at this point, and your Application does not implement Configuration.Provider.
Class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 Stack trace: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is not initialized properly.  You have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, have not manually called WorkManager#initialize at this point, and your Application does not implement Configuration.Provider.
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.getInstance(WorkManagerImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.work.WorkManager.getInstance(WorkManager.java:184)
```

I do not see anything related to this in AndroidManifest.xml, so I am not sure what "You have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest" means.

Could anyone shed some light on this to help me find the culprit?

Again, it is very rare.
[Edit]

The code of the app using WorkManager is the following:

```
OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WidgetUpdateWorker.class).build();
WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniqueWork(WidgetUpdateWorker.WIDGET_UPDATE_WORK, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, oneTimeWorkRequest);
```

The following is from [the official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#getInstance(android.content.Context)):

> By default, WorkManager auto-initializes itself using a built-in
> ContentProvider. ContentProviders are created and run before the
> Application object, so this allows the WorkManager singleton to be
> setup before your code can run in most cases.

As for the method initialize (Context context, Configuration configuration):

> Used to do a one-time initialization of the WorkManager singleton with
> a custom Configuration. By default, this method should not be called
> because WorkManager is automatically initialized.

Comment: Do you call `WorkManager.initialize(...)` in your code?

Comment: No, it is never called by the app.

Comment: The exception message suggests you need to call that

Comment: It is hard to post code in a comment, so I edited my question by adding the code and quotes about  initialize (Context context, Configuration configuration)

Comment: Ah i see - sorry i'm not sure what else to suggest